# T-SQL replace function missing some occurrences with nvarchar(max)

Tags: t-sql, replace, sql-server-2012

Given the following T-SQL code:

```
declare @lf char(1) set @lf = char(10);
declare @cr char(1) set @cr = char(13);

select  replace(isnull(note,''), @cr+@lf,@lf)  from T
```

are there circumstances where not every occurrence of @cr+@lf in the `note` column would be replaced with @lf?

I am trying to troubleshoot a situation where that is indeed happening.

The `note` column is defined as `nvarchar(max)`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says:

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLACE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to a large-value data type.

If I understand that correctly, there's no need to cast because `note` is already of the proper datatype to allow for return values greater than 8000 bytes.

I thought maybe the `isnull` function was not returning `nvarchar(max)` but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says it returns the type of the value being tested:

> ... Return Types
>   Returns the same type as check_expression.

And the returned value isn't being truncated; it's just that some crlf pairs are being overlooked.

I must be overlooking something.

```
declare @t table( notes nvarchar(max));

insert @t(notes)
values
(
'From: kkkkkkk@aaaaaaaaa.com <kkkkkkk@aaaaaaaaa.com> 
Sent: Monday, May 00, 0008 00:55 PM
To: Jan Zzzz <sZzzz@dddd.dd.com>
Subject: RE: [Secure Message] aaaaaaaaa ABC ddddddddddddd--XXXXX-X

Hi Jan, 

The ddddddddddddd is valid for one year.  I have attached the Zzzzzzz Rrrrrrrr which you will find behind the  blank cover page and ddddddddddddd form.  Please let me know if this is what you need.  

Best Regards, 

Yyyyyy 

Kkkkkkkk Kkkkkk, ABC, DEF
ABC Mmmmmmmm
P 800.007.0000 ext 000 | F 600.000.0070 



Electronic mail is not considered to be a secure form of communication for Protected Health Information. If you are concerned about privacy, please call aaaaaaaaa directly at 0-800-007-0000. If you would like to review our privacy policy, it can be found on our website: www.ddddddddddddd.com.

This email, including any attached files, may contain confidential and privileged information for the sole use of the intended recipient(s). Any review, use, distribution or disclosure by others is strictly prohibited. If you are not the addressee indicated in this message (or authorized to receive information for the recipient), please contact the sender by reply e-mail and delete all copies of this message (including any attachments).

From: Jan Zzzz <sZzzz@dddd.dd.com> 
Sent: Monday, May 00, 0008 8:56 AM
To: Kkkkkkkk Kkkkkk <kkkkkkk@aaaaaaaaa.com>; Jan Zzzz <sZzzz@dddd.dd.com>
Subject: Re: [Secure Message] aaaaaaaaa ABC ddddddddddddd--XXXXX-X

Hi, this expired, I need a copy of the aaaaaaa aaaa so I can submit my aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa. Thank you. SZzzz

On 0/00/0008 8:00 AM, Jan Zzzz wrote:
Thank you for the dddddddd, I am mmmmmmm mmm today.

On 0/0/0008 6:05 PM, Kkkkkkkk Kkkkkk wrote:

[Secure Message] aaaaaaaaa ABC ddddddddddddd--XXXXX-X    

Kkkkkkkk Kkkkkk has sent you a secure message.
Subject:    aaaaaaaaa ABC ddddddddddddd--XXXXX-X
From:   Kkkkkkkk Kkkkkk <kkkkkkk@aaaaaaaaa.com>

To: Jan Zzzz <sZzzz@dddd.dd.com>

Expires:    May 00, 0008

View Secure Message 



Note: If you have any concerns about the authenticity of this message please contact the original sender directly.'   
)

select notes from @t;
select replace(notes, char(13),'') from @t;
```

[image: Redacted Record Shown in Notepad++]

Comment: "troubleshoot a situation where that is indeed happening." Can you perhaps create a reproducible example?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean  I am in the process of putting something together but since this is a time-sensitive project, I was hoping the issue would just "jump out" at someone who'd encountered it before.

Comment: Tip: You can display the datatype of an expression: `select SQL_Variant_Property( IsNull( Note, '' ), 'BaseType' )`. See [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for additional data available.

Comment: @HABO: error: "Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with sql_variant"  But I guess the info you need is there in the error :)

Comment: This data is being written to SQL Server from a desktop application using ADO.NET and the System.Data.SqlClient libraries. In my mock-up I've used a table variable.

Comment: Does not repro, I think you have a different issue like CRs being added to the viewer in SSMS or whatever is consuming the stripped string or maybe you are concatenating strings and only replacing the CRs in one part. I ran this to show the CRs were removed correctly. `UPDATE @t SET notes=replace(notes, char(13),'');` `SELECT * FROM @t WHERE notes like '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'`

Answer (score 1):

You would be left with `@cr+@lf` in the `SELECT` if `@cr+@cr+@lf` occurs in the `note`, unless you need `@cr` when it occurs on its own you are probably better off doing:

```
declare @cr char(1) set @cr = char(13);

select  replace(isnull(note,''), @cr,'')  from T
```

Comment: I cannot replace individually occuring @cr.    Only the pair should be turned into a LF.  The data in the field is @cr@lf@cr@lf@cr@lf@cr@lf.  Four pairs in a row.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data of when the issue occurs in the question? Note: if data in `note` was `@cr@lf@cr@lf@cr@lf@cr@lf` both methods would change it to `@lf@lf@lf@lf`

Comment: of the troubled field, please provide the hex values CAST(note AS VARBINARY(50)) where id = whatever

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik : This is real production data. When you cast the varbinary back into nvarchar(max) it is the email address of someone in our organization.

Comment: @Tim - I understand you not wanting to share production data, but without a minimum viable example I don't think we can get much further, could you change all the letters to a? If that still has the bug, share that with us e.g. `ryan@sparks.rocks   => aaaa@aaaaaa.aaaaa   => 0x610061006100610040006100610061006100610061002E00610061006100610061000D000A00`

Comment: @Ryan Sparks:  The code snippet I've now appended to the question replicates the problem.

Comment: @Tim - White space characters don't tend to copy very well, I imagine SO is striping whatever causes the issue, as your example code is working fine for me. When you copy the code directly from SO, does it still have the bug? If not, could you have the example start in hex, and preferably try deleting some of the text and see if the bug is still there (2157 characters is a lot to search through)

Comment: @Ryan Sparks: With dummy data I cannot replicate the first problem I reported, where some of the CRLF pairs are not reduced to a single LF while others are.  What I can reproduce with the dummy data is that SSMS will add a CR wherever it sees a lone LF, if you have "Retain CR/LF on copy or save" set to true.

Comment: I've added a screen capture of the redacted record, displayed in Notepad++, showing how in the upper section of the record the CRLF pairs have been converted to LF only using the `replace()` function, but a few CRLF pairs at the bottom of the record have remained unchanged.  The only unusual thing I see in that section of the record are the glyphs indicating a TAB but these glyphs vary in their length. Not sure what these TAB glyphs mean. I have to research Notepad++ conventions.

Answer (score 1):

if its just a single line, this should do it, remove them all and put it back

```
set @note =  replace(replace(isnull(@note,''),@cr,''),@lf,'')+@lf . //or whatever line endings you want
```

if its multi line try something like this

```
declare @note as nvarchar(max)
declare @lf char(1) set @lf = char(10);
declare @cr char(1) set @cr = char(13);

set @note = 'A'+char(10)+char(13)+char(10)+char(13)+char(10)+char(13)+char(10)+char(13)+'A'+char(10)+char(13)

set @note = replace(isnull(@note,''),@cr,'')

--not sure if you want to keep all the user lf's but if you want only one try this?
if (patindex(isnull(@note,''),@lf+@lf) >= 0)
begin
set @note = replace(isnull(@note,''),@lf+@lf,@lf)
end 

select @note
select cast(@note as VARBINARY(100))
select len(@note)
```

Comment: this was only for one field, and looking at his example,  @note didnt quite make it into my brain ::grabs more coffee::

Answer (score 0):

Every circumstance will be replaced, but you might be creating some CrLfs via your replace. Please see the example below and how to mitigate it.

```
DECLARE @Cr CHAR(1)=CHAR(13)
DECLARE @Lf CHAR(1)=CHAR(10)
DECLARE @CrLf CHAR(2)=CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
DECLARE @NoteTbl TABLE(Note NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @NoteTbl (Note) SELECT @Cr + @CrLf

--example can result in CrLF being created
SELECT [NewNote],LEN([NewNote]) FROM (SELECT replace(isnull(note,''), @CrLf,@lf) AS [NewNote] FROM @NoteTbl) AS a

--Option 1: Replace all Cr with nothing; this is effectively the same as replacing CrLf with Lf
SELECT [NewNote],LEN([NewNote]) FROM (SELECT replace(isnull(note,''), @Cr,'') AS [NewNote] FROM @NoteTbl) AS a

--Option 2: insert the notes into a table and loop until CrLf is gone, this might be useful if you need to do multiple different  data scrubs
DECLARE @NotesCleaned TABLE(Note NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @NotesCleaned (Note) SELECT Note FROM @NoteTbl
WHILE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM @NotesCleaned WHERE Note Like '%' + @CrLf + '%'
)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @NotesCleaned SET Note=replace(isnull(note,''), @CrLf,@lf)
    END

SELECT Note,LEN(Note) FROM @NotesCleaned
```

Comment: I've confirmed that the CRLF pairs are not being created as a side-effect of the removal, e.g. nothing like this exists in the data:  CR CRLF LF.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found a partial answer.  In SSMS:

```
Tools->Options->SQL Server->Results to Grid

[ x ]  Retain CR/LF on copy or save
```

will actually *restore* the CR that your call to `replace()` has removed.